# How can I reset the sliding doors without disconnecting the battery

Tags: honda, electrical, troubleshooting, door, odyssey

My 2017 Honda Odyssey driver side sliding door will not open or close via the power buttons. I’ve done some online research to attempt to diagnose the issue, and something I’ve seen a few times is the idea that sometimes issues can be resolved by “resetting” the power doors. However, I cannot seem to find good instructions for how to accomplish this.

I’ve read of two methods for resetting the doors:

1. Disconnect the vehicle’s battery
2. Press/hold door buttons in a certain order (like an old school video game cheat code)

I would like to avoid disconnecting the battery unless it’s absolutely necessary. But the instructions I’ve found for using the door control buttons are vague.

How can I reset the doors using just the door controls?

[image: door control panel]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: One thing you could try is to remove the fuse for the door, wait a few seconds and then put it back in. While you are at it check the fuse to see if it's good.